# Find the Smallest Value

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Find the smallest value of $$a + \frac {1}{(a-b)b} $$  where a>b>0

I found this question in AM-GM inequality problems but I am stuck at this

Comment: Tagged number-theory: does this mean $a,b$ are integers?  That would change the problem significantly :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1) $a>b$ denote $$a=b+x, x \geqslant 0$$
2) Prove $$f= b+x+\frac{1}{bx} \geqslant 3$$

Comment: how the $f \ge 3?$

Comment: AM-GM for $b,x, \frac{1}{bx}$

Comment: it is $$b+x+\frac{1}{bx}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{bx}{bx}}=3$$